# Dozer + Hibernate update causes "Identifier of an instance..."

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dozer

I'm facing a problem about updating objects in database, after Dozer mapping.
I looked a lot on the Internet and I didn't find anybody with the same issue.

My architecture :

- Hibernate
- Dozer
- Model beans
- VO beans (DTO bean which maps totaly or
  partially model beans)

I have some DAO and service layers but it's not on what I want to focus here.

In my example, I have an Action @ManyToOne mapped with a Segment :

```
@Entity
class Action {
   @Id
   Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   Segment segment;
}
```

and the VO class :

```
class ActionVO {
   Long id;
   SegmentVO segment;
}
```

Here is the main pseudo code (in a single transaction) :

```
Long idAction = 1;
Long idSegment = 2;

Mapper mapper; // Dozer mapper

Action action = findById(idAction);
ActionVO actionVO = new ActionVO;
mapper.map(action, actionVO);

Segment segment = findById(idSegment);
SegmentVO segmentVO = new SegmentVO;
mapper.map(segment, segmentVO);

// here, the segment of the action has the id = 1 : actionVO.getSegment().getId() => 1

actionVO.setSegment(segmentVO);

// here, the segment of the action has the id = 2 : actionVO.getSegment().getId() => 2

mapper.map(actionVO, action);

action = save(action); // throw an hibernate exception
```

When saving the Action with the changed Segment attribute, hibernate throws an exception like :

> identifier of an instance of was altered from 1 to 2

I know the origin of the problem : Dozer maps objects attributes without creating new (if exists), so the attribute segment is the same object with updated attributes. So Hibernate see that the Segment object of the Action is still the same, but with different attributes value, including the id. Hibernate tries to update the primary key of a Segment, which is not permitted.

My question is : how can I solve this problem whithout changing my architecture ? If not possible, what is the best practice when using Dozer and Hibernate together ?

Thx !

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having exactly the same architecture and problem:)

Comment: Hello, I'm not working on this project anymore, but I think that the solution was by doing two updates. The first with a null value, and the second with the new Segment. Or maybe without the first save. At any rate, the solution is to don't have the save object when saving as when loading with hibernate. Tell me if it works.